# Tensorflow Setup for Distributed Computing

Tags: c++, tensorflow

Can anyone provide guidance on how to setup tensorflow to work on many CPUs across a network? All of the examples I have found thus far use only one local box and multi-gpus at best. I have found that I can pass in a list of targets in the session_opts, but I'm not sure how to setup tensorflow on each box to listen for networked nodes/tasks. Any example would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The open-source version (currently 0.6.0) of TensorFlow supports single-process execution only: in particular, the only valid target in the `tensorflow::SessionOptions` is the empty string, which means "current process."

The [TensorFlow whitepaper](http://download.tensorflow.org/paper/whitepaper2015.pdf) describes the structure of the distributed implementation (see Figure 3) that we use inside Google. The basic idea is that the Session interface can be implemented using RPC to a *master*; and the master can partition the computation across a set of devices in multiple *worker* processes, which also communicate using RPC. Alas, the current version depends heavily on Google-internal technologies (like [Borg](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/43438.pdf)), so a lot of work remains to make it ready for external consumption. We are currently working on this, and you can follow the progress on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/23).

**EDIT on 2/26/2016:** Today we released an [initial version of the distributed runtime](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime) to GitHub. It supports multiple machines and multiple GPUs.